How to prevent slickR from removing inputs and how to keep original size?
I have a shiny app where I'm trying to update some plots to slickR. I'm getting some unexpected effects:

The card_footer disappears.
How can I keep the original height and width and make it resize when I collapse the sidebar as if I would just plotOutput?
I get a scroll bar for the plot although there is space below.

library(shiny)
library(slickR)
library(svglite)
library(tidyverse)
library(gdtools)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <-
  page_fluid(layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = tagList(
      pickerInput("select_a", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_b", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_c", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_d", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10])
    ) ,
    
    bslib::accordion(open = FALSE, accordion_panel("Ab Panel", actionButton("run", "Run"))),
    
    #plotOutput("plt"), slickROutput("slickr"), card_footer(card_body( layout_column_wrap( width = 1 / 2, actionButton("ab1", "Go1"), actionButton("ab2", "Go2") ) ))
    
  ))

server <-
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$plt <-
      renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
        
      })
    
    output$slickr <-
      renderSlickR({
        slickR(svglite::xmlSVG({
          methods::show(ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point())
        }, standalone = TRUE))
        
      })
    
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)


The inputs are not removed, but simply hidden beneath the svg which is 7 x 7 inches by default. Assuming a DPI of 96 this exceeds the default height (400px) of the slickROutput.
Thus, you need to tell xmlSVG to use suitable dimensions and bring them in-sync with the height and the widths of the output. You can use session$clientData$output_slickr_width which gives you the current width of the slickr output width in pixels and use this information to transform to inches:
library(shiny)
library(slickR)
library(svglite)
library(tidyverse)
library(gdtools)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

p2i <- function(pixels, dpi = 96) {
  pixels / dpi
}

## anyways defaults but explicit beats implicit
height <- 400
width <- "100%"

ui <-
  page_fluid(
    layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = tagList(
      pickerInput("select_a", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_b", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_c", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10]),
      pickerInput("select_d", "Select", choices = LETTERS[1:10])
    ) ,
    
    bslib::accordion(open = FALSE, accordion_panel("Ab Panel", actionButton("run", "Run"))),
    plotOutput("plt"),
    slickROutput("slickr", width = width, height = height), 
    card_footer(
      card_body(
        layout_column_wrap(width = 1 / 2, 
                           actionButton("ab1", "Go1"), 
                           actionButton("ab2", "Go2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  )



server <-
  function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$plt <-
      renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
        
      })
    
    output$slickr <-
      renderSlickR({
        plt <- svglite::xmlSVG({
          show(
            ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
          )
        }, height = p2i(height), width = p2i(session$clientData$output_slickr_width), 
        standalone = TRUE)
        slickR(
          list(plt, plt)
        )
      })
    
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)


